# Use case diagram -usage of "includes"

Tags: uml, software-design, use-case

consider the follwing use case diagram
(say the user login to a system, fills a form and submits to the server)

```
   (Fill in Form) --<<includes>>---->(Login)
            ^
            \                         ^
          <<includes>>               /
              \                     / 
            (sumbit)------<<includes>>     <------- Is this include necassary ?
```

`now "Submit" includes "Login"`
 `again "Submit" includes "Fill in Form" which includes "Login"`

The two 'includes' seem unnecassary.
By including "Fill in Form" it automatically includes "Login" or not? What is correct?

Comment: seems I can't attach the image.used Ascii :(

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about your UML but in this scenario 
***user 1st login with authentication like***

User-----> enter Login details-----> press submit button-----> if authenticate-----> fill form---->  press submit button---->

In case user is not authenticate system will show error message.